# Shiny - How do I code parallel processing for source()-ed scripts within an action button?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, widget, shiny, shiny-server

My R script is highly variable, so I have broken it up into a series of source()-ed R files that are run by a controller script. If I want a script to run, I create an object and wrap the source()-ed scripts with a conditional statement. I want to use shiny's programmable widgets to control the inputs, but I also still want to have the freedom to run the code through RStudio. In order to run it in R, I have created an Rlauncher script where you can manually set the object parameters and source() the controller script. Unfortunately with the SHINYlauncher (server.R), the wrapped actionButton() required to isolate all the inputs and run the script requires the code to run in shiny's .GlobalEnv. I have come up with a partial solution to run the server.R parallel to the original script but I cannot get around source()-ing the controller script in the .GlobalEnv. Any help on how to munipulate the environment to run the controller script in the parent.frame() would be awesome!

This is my original code. If I load my objects onto the .GlobalEnv when I run the controller script, everything works, but it takes me WEEKS to render a batch of maps...

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

observe({
if (input$actnBut_runController==0) {return} else{
isolate({
  tmp.env <- new.env()
  run_script1 <- input$run_script1
  run_script2 <- input$run_script2
  run_script3 <- input$run_script3
  assign("run_script1",run_script1,envir=tmp.env)
  assign("run_script2",run_script2,envir=tmp.env)
  assign("run_script3",run_script3,envir=tmp.env)
  save(list=ls(all.names=TRUE,pos=tmp.env),envir=tmp.env,file="obs.RData")
  rm(tmp.env)
  })
  print("Running sourced scripts...")
  source("controller.R"),echo=TRUE)
}
})
```

This code mimics parallel coding I have seen from other working examples. It will create the objects and run the controller script but I still can't seem to get it to run in the parent.frame().

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

iso_obs <- function() {
  Sys.sleep(1)
  shiny::isolate({
     tmp.env <- new.env()
     run_script1 <- input$run_script1
     run_script2 <- input$run_script2
     run_script3 <- input$run_script3
     assign("run_script1",run_script1,envir=tmp.env)
     assign("run_script2",run_script2,envir=tmp.env)
     assign("run_script3",run_script3,envir=tmp.env)
     save(list=ls(all.names=TRUE,pos=tmp.env),envir=tmp.env,file="obs.RData")
     rm(tmp.env)
     })}

runController <- reactive({
if (input$actnBut_runController==0) {return} else {
  iso_obs()
  print("Running sourced scripts...")
  source("controller.R"),echo=TRUE)
}})
```

This code also creates the objects but doesn't run the controller script properly. I tried to have two functions executing for the same input, where the source()-ed code is a delayed function.

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

observe({
if (input$actnBut_runController==0) {return} else{
isolate({
  tmp.env <- new.env()
  run_script1 <- input$run_script1
  run_script2 <- input$run_script2
  run_script3 <- input$run_script3
  assign("run_script1",run_script1,envir=tmp.env)
  assign("run_script2",run_script2,envir=tmp.env)
  assign("run_script3",run_script3,envir=tmp.env)
  save(list=ls(all.names=TRUE,pos=tmp.env),envir=tmp.env,file="obs.RData")
  rm(tmp.env)
  })
}
})

runController <- reactive({
if (input$actnBut_runController==0) {return} else {
  Sys.sleep(1) # This is to delay the R environment so .GlobalEnv can create objects
  print("Running sourced scripts...")
  source("controller.R"),echo=TRUE)
}
})
```

Comment: Use functions with arguments instead of sourcing scripts that use global variables.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the "local=TRUE" option to your "source()" function call.